# Permissions to access storage for Telegram app

Tags: permissions, storage, telegram, upload

Ubuntu 18.04, recent update, now 18.04.5.
Telegram works well in other respects. Suddenly  telegram desktop hangs needs force quit, as I attempt to upload a file png jpg etc.
all worked well before update I think.telegram permissions in Ubuntu software centre are ON.
all is ok in my account when using android mobile phone.
Comments appreciated. Tia

edit: the hang occurs immediately I access the file manager without selection of a file. If I close the file manager, hang  still in place. Earlier I change the default file manager from nautilus to nemo in the hope the problem might go away, no luck.

Comment: Hello, welcome to AskUbuntu. How did you install Telegram?

Comment: install - ah good question, I checked and although it is in ubuntu software centre (now) it looks like I first used (tsetup.2.5.1.tar.xz) in my downloads folder, so it presumably has not integrated fully. so there might be a config outside of the system. Will look. Thanks for the question. YES! There is an updater in the install folder non software centre, run updater, - fixed it! (very unusual for me to instal  via tar. Thanks!!

Comment: FYI:  18.04.5 was nearly a year ago (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, installed systems get the update before that date) so if you only upgraded to 18.04.5 recently - you should upgrade more often (*11 months ago isn't really recent*)

Answer (score 2):

solved. Install was via (tsetup.2.5.1.tar.xz) in download folder - so it was outside the ubuntu software umbrella - unusual for me. The Updater in the telegram install, setup folder - run once again, fixed it.